# When creating a symbolic link, how do I troubleshoot 'too many levels of symbolic links'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, shell, symbolic-link

I'm trying to create a symbolic link on Ubuntu 10.04 ((Lucid Lynx)) it says:

```
me@laptop:~/PHPUnit$ ls
assertions.php      LICENSE      PHPUnit           README.markdown
build.xml           package.xml  phpunit.bat       Tests
ChangeLog.markdown  phpunit      phpunit.xml.dist
me@laptop:~/PHPUnit$ ln -s phpunit /usr/bin/phpunit
ln: accessing `/usr/bin/phpunit': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

And when I do `/usr/bin$ ls php*` I just get:

```
php  php5  php-config  php-config5  phpize  phpize5
```

I tried to create it before, and I'm not sure if I run a wrong command...

Comment: try to specify the full path of phpunit

Answer (score 30):

Beware that using `ln -s target /path/symlink`, the `target` will be interpreted as relative to the `path` directory (where the symlink will belong).
Your command would create a symlink that points to itself. Hence, a path lookup loop would occur every time the symlink is accessed.

In your case, maybe `/usr/bin/phpunit` already exists and is self-looping. Remove it first and change your command to:

```
me@laptop:~/PHPUnit$ ln -s ~/PHPUnit/phpunit /usr/bin/phpunit
```

(Using an absolute target is probably the best here)